# what is the regular expression to deny "?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular5

I need to validate that I don't allow double quotes in my form

```
Validators.pattern(/^[^"]/g)
```

But that doesn't work. I need to let him put any character but not double quotes

Comment: There is no quotes in an empty string.

Comment: `^[^"]+$` but is the form escape tolerant of a quote `\"` ? I mean is this a strictly visual thing, like a turd in the sink ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `/[^"]*/g` to match all characters that aren't `"`. You don't need the first caret, but you do need the `*` to allow any numbre of non-quotation characters.

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work as I expect. 

'description': [this.article.description, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/[^"]*/g)
        ]
      ],